# Drawing rectangles/squares with characters in console

Tags: java

I have this code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
                if (i == 0 || i == a - 1 || j == 0 || j == b - 1) {
                    System.out.print("* ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I need it to draw in a way that doesn't outputs space after each line.

I tried to modify the code in a variety of different ways, but couldn't come up with a solution.

Comment: **need it to draw in a way that doesn't outputs space after each line.**. Can you elaborate this more?

Comment: This code outputs a space in the end of each line, but spaces between " * " are required, I just need it not to print the space in the end after the last " * " on each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you have two choices.

1. Print a space after each `*` – except for the last one.
2. Print a space before each `*` – except for the first one.

For me, the second option is easier to implement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            boolean first = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
                if (i == 0 || i == a - 1 || j == 0 || j == b - 1) {
                    if (first) {
                        first = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                    System.out.print("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Before the start of each row, I set the flag indicating that I am about to start a new row. Hence on the first iteration of the inner loop, I print just the characters `*`. Then in every subsequent iteration (of the inner loop) I print a single space and then I print a single `*`. Thus no extra space at the end of the row.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the case for `j == b - 1` and print `"*"` instead of `"* "` for that case only.

```
if(j == b - 1) {
    System.out.print("*");
} else if(i == 0 || i == a - 1 || j == 0) {
    System.out.print("* ");
} else {
    System.out.print("  ");
}
```

Comment: This code is not working.